# jQuery Inserting Text into a Textarea at the Cursor Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen this example floating around on how to insert text at the cursor in a text area:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/bTUWa/5/

The above works fine but when I've tried to add it to my own code (which is primarily jQuery) I find I can't get it to work anymore - below is an example of my code trying to use the function:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/bbE48/6/

Can someone help me get the second jsfiddle working. Note: really want to pass the ID across as there are many div's with different ID's but all have the same textarea.classname within.

thankyou

```
<div id="100000000">
  <input id="insertPattern" type="button" value="insert pattern" />
  <textarea class="chatMessengerFooterTextArea">insert some text into this string</textarea>
</div>​
```

Comment: Alert your 'br' variable and it's coming out as 'false'. Looks like the browser detection isn't working as expected. Note: I'm using FF

Comment: Please don't post questions containing nothing but jsfiddles. That isn't how this site works. I need to be able to answer your question without opening any external links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next` to get the input:

```
var txtarea = $("#"+ID).next('textarea')[0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbE48/13/

Comment: great... thankyou... makes good sense... the first textarea... cheers

Comment: You saved me friend (y)!

Answer (score 0):

Your modified function redefines the `txtarea` variable to be a jQuery object instead of the DOM object. You need to use `.get(0)` to get the DOM object again.

```
var txtarea = $("#"+ID).find('textarea.chatMessengerFooterTextArea').get(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the textarea itself an ID.  You are passing the :) into the DIV, not the textarea.

Change your textarea to something like this:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" class="chatMessengerFooterTextArea">insert some text into this string</textarea>
```

And your Jquery code to this:

```
$('input#insertPattern').click(function() {
    alert('clicked me');
    insertEmoticonAtTextareaCursor('myTextArea', ':)');
});
```

Comment: He's not. He's got an extra jQuery find() in his function to get the textarea.